# getting Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails in a registration form in Swift

Tags: json, swift

im very new in the iOS envelopment, and I'm trying to do an registration
 app with The library Alamofire, This is my JSON.php

```
   <?php

//importing required script
require_once 'include/DbOperation.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!verifyRequiredParams(array('userName','pass','sexo','edad','origen','motivo','visita','perfil'))) {
        //getting values
        $userName = $_POST['userName'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
        $edad = $_POST['edad'];
        $origen = $_POST['origen'];
        $motivo = $_POST['motivo'];
        $visita = $_POST['visita'];
        $perfil = $_POST['perfil'];

        //creating db operation object
        $db = new DbOperation();
        //adding user to database
        $result = $db->createUser($userName,$pass,$sexo,$edad,$origen,$motivo,$visita,$perfil);

        //making the response accordingly
        if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = 'Usuario creado Exitosamente';
        } elseif ($result == USER_ALREADY_EXIST) {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Usuario ya existente';
        } elseif ($result == USER_NOT_CREATED) {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Ha ocurrido un error';
        }
    } else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Parametros no encontrados';
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Solicitud invalida';
}

//function to validate the required parameter in request
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields)
{

    //Getting the request parameters
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;

    //Looping through all the parameters
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        //if any requred parameter is missing
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {

            //returning true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

echo json_encode($response);echo json_encode($response);
```

and this is my Swift code, it gets the connection to the server and made the user registration, but when I try to get the message whit the result I get an error

```
//
//  Register.swift
//  ConoceTepic2.0
//
//  Created by ITIL9 on 04/03/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ITIL9. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SQLite3


class regUser: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

    //Defined a constant that holds the URL for our web service
    let URL_REGISTER = "https://aleios.000webhostapp.com/aleWeb/Register.php"
    //
    let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSexo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEdad: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtUsuario: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var dos: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var uno: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tres: UITextField!

    var thePicker1 = UIPickerView()
    var thePicker2 = UIPickerView()
    var thePicker3 = UIPickerView()
    var thePicker4 = UIPickerView()

    let myPickerMotivo = [String](arrayLiteral: " ","Negocio", "Placer", "Compras")

    let myPickerEstado = [String](arrayLiteral: " ","Aguascalientes", "Baja California", "Baja California Sur", "Campeche", "CDMX", "Chiapas", "Chihuahua", "Coahuila", "Colima", "Durango", "Edo.Mex","Guanajuato","Guerrero","Hidalgo","Jalisco","Michoacan","Morelos","Nayarit", "Nuevo León", "Oaxaca", "Puebla”, “Querétaro","Quintana Roo","San Luis Potosí", "Sinaloa", "Tabasco", "Tamaulipas", "Tlaxcala", "Veracruz", "Yucatán", "Zacatecas", "Internacional")

    let myPickerVisita = [String](arrayLiteral: " ","Solo", "Pareja", "familia", "Compañero de trabajo")
    let myPickerSexo = [String](arrayLiteral: "","Femenino", "Masculino")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        uno.inputView=thePicker1
        dos.inputView = thePicker2
        tres.inputView = thePicker3
        txtSexo.inputView = thePicker4

        thePicker1.delegate = self
        thePicker3.delegate = self
        thePicker2.delegate = self
        thePicker4.delegate = self

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //funciones para los selects

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView == thePicker1){
            return myPickerMotivo.count
        }else if (pickerView == thePicker2){
            return myPickerEstado.count
        }else if (pickerView == thePicker3){
            return myPickerVisita.count
        }else{
            return myPickerSexo.count
        }
    }


    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView == thePicker1){
            return myPickerMotivo[row]
        }else if (pickerView == thePicker2){
            return myPickerEstado[row]
        }else if (pickerView == thePicker3){
            return myPickerVisita[row]
        }else{
            return myPickerSexo[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if (pickerView == thePicker1){
            uno.text=myPickerMotivo[row]
        }else if (pickerView == thePicker2){
            dos.text = myPickerEstado[row]
        }else if (pickerView == thePicker3){
            tres.text=myPickerVisita[row]
        }else{
            txtSexo.text = myPickerSexo[row]
        }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func btnEnvio(_ sender: UIButton) {

        var perfil: String
        var sex: String
        var selecM: String
        var selecV: String

        var edad: String

        var edad2:String
        edad2=txtEdad.text!
        sex = txtSexo.text!
        perfil=""
        selecM=uno.text!
        selecV=tres.text!

        if selecM == "Negocio" && selecV == "Pareja" {
            perfil = "3"
        }else if selecM == "Negocio" && selecV == "Familia"{
            perfil = "4"
        }else if selecM == "Negocio" && selecV == "Compañero de trabajo"{
            perfil = "5"
        }else if selecM == "Placer" && selecV == "Solo" && sex == "Femenino"{
            perfil = "7"
        }else if selecM == "Placer" && selecV == "Solo" && sex == "Masculino"{
            perfil = "6"
        }else if selecM == "Placer" && selecV == "Pareja" || selecM == "Placer" && selecV == "Familia"{
            perfil = "8"
        }else if selecM == "Placer" && selecV == "Compañero de trabajo" {
            perfil = "10"
        }else if selecM == "Compras" && selecV == "Solo" || selecM == "Compras" && selecV == "pareja" || selecM == "Compras" && selecV == "Compañero de trabajo" {
            perfil = "11"
        }else if selecM == "Compras" && selecV == "Familia"{
            perfil = "13"
        }else if selecM == "Negocio" && selecV == "Solo" && sex == "Femenino"{
            perfil = "2"
        }else if selecM == "Negocios" && selecV == "Solo" && sex == "Masculino"{
            perfil = "1"
        }else if edad2 == "65" {
            perfil = "14"
        }


        //isertTableUsuario(usu,pass)
        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "userName":txtUsuario.text!,
            "pass":txtPassword.text!,
            "sexo":txtSexo.text!,
            "edad":txtEdad.text!,
            "origen":dos.text!,
            "motivo":uno.text!,
            "visita":tres.text!,
            "perfil":perfil
        ]

        print("Valor parametros",parameters)
        //se envia la peticion http mediante el metodo post
        Alamofire.request(URL_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString{
            response in
            //Se muestran los resultados en la consola
            print(response)

            //se obtienen los valores desde el servidor
            if let result = response.result.value{
                print("Dentro del if result")
                //converting it as NSDictionary
               // let jsonData = result.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary //Here is where i get the next messge "Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails"


                //displaying the message in label
                self.label.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
            }
        }

        txtEdad.text = " "
        txtPassword.text = " "
        txtUsuario.text = " "
        txtSexo.text = " "
        dos.text = " "
        uno.text = " "
        tres.text = " "


    }
    }
```

Comment: unrelated: `[String](arrayLiteral: " ","Negocio", "Placer", "Compras")` is a really complicated way of just saying `[" ","Negocio", "Placer", "Compras"]`

Comment: `response.result.value` is a String. So why should it be a `Dictionary`?. Instead of `responseString`, did you meant `responseJSON`?

Comment: @Larme if I use responseJSOn I get an error like this FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}))  and  I don't really know what it does mean, I found a post that say it was because of the way  was estructurate the JSON  JSON  and that im suppose to use responseString

Comment: `print(response)`: What's the output? I don't have knownledge in PHP to debug it, but the output of response might help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this code will help you, but it is an example of how to call a REST API using `Alamofire` in `Swift4`. It is from a book that I recommend. The book was written by Christina Moulton. She is very helpful with answering questions (via email) that you may have while you are working through the book.  Here is the link to the book: http://leanpub.com/iosappswithrest.  Here is the code:

```
let todoEndpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" 
Alamofire.request(todoEndpoint)
.responseJSON { response in
    // get errors
    if let error = response.result.error {
      print(error)
    }
    // get serialized data (i.e., JSON)
    if let value = response.result.value { 
        print(value)
    }
    // get raw data
    if let data = response.data { 
        print(data)
    }
    // get HTTPURLResponse
    if let httpResponse = response.response { 
        print(httpResponse)
    } 
}
```